# how ES7 import module's object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-2017

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
```

How can I use ES2017's way to write it? I try

```
import GoogleStrategy from ('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
```

But it couldn't work

How can I use ES7 to write it?
Thanks

here is the package.json file,
It set the type as module.
So I couldn't use const...=require('...')

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
```

Comment: It’s `import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';`.